# How much water could be stored?

Tags: volume, classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics

We have two water storage tanks--- Tank A and Tank B --- on the roof of the upper storey of our two-storey house.

The tanks are cylindrical in shape.

Each of the two tanks have a circular opening at the top.

Tank A has a capacity of about 500 gallons, whereas Tank B has a capacity of about 300 gallons.

The two tanks are placed on the same horizontal surface and are connected through an iron pipe.

The water is drawn up with the help of an electric motor and pumped into one of the tanks through a pipe via the opening at the top.

With this arrangement, how much water could be stored?

And how can we achieve the maximum storage capacity of 800 gallons, without changing the position of the tanks?

Exactly which area of mathematics do such problems properly belong?

And, how to tackle such problems?

Comment: You should probably try asking this on the [physics SE site](http://physics.stackexchange.com/).  I'm not quite sure I understand what's going on here; what's stopping us from filling both tanks completely?  Is the idea that the 300-gallon tank would overflow?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, exactly. Each of the two tanks have a circular opening at the top.

Comment: Indeed, the archetypal  [Professor Calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Professor_Calculus) may come up with an answer that looks great but has little to do with the practical situation at hand.

Comment: @SaaqibMahmuud What matters here, then, is the height of the top of each tank, and that alone.

Comment: @SaaqibMahmuud see the wiki page on [communicating vessels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communicating_vessels)

Comment: @CountIblis Tintin! Haven't read that in years!

Comment: The easiest way to be able to fill both tanks up fully would be to connect the hole on the top of the small tank to the large tank. So one pipe would feed the large tank, which would have another pipe feeding the small tank. Of course, getting the water out might be annoying. But it's just as annoying as the presented problem (there isn't a way).